# Expected value of the conditional choice probability

Tags: normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

I would like to compute the conditional choice probability which is defined as follows

\begin{equation}
p_k=Prob(f(m_k)+u_k>f(m_i)+u_i, \forall  i\neq k|m)
\end{equation}

where $u_i, i=1,...,N$ are independently and identically distributed normal variables with $u_i\sim N(0,\sigma_i^2)$ and $m_i, i=1,...,N$ are independently and identically distributed standard uniform random variables, $m_i\sim i.i.d. U[0,1]$.  In words, $p_k$ is the probability that out of $N$ options, the choice $k$ has the greatest value conditional on having a realization for the vector $m$.

Because $u_i-u_k\sim N(0, \sigma_i^2+\sigma_k^2)$, $p_k$ can be rewritten as

\begin{equation}p_k=\prod_{i\neq k}\Phi\left(\frac{f(m_k)-f(m_i)}{\sqrt{\sigma_i+\sigma_k}}|m\right)
\end{equation}
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ denotes the CDF of standard normal distribution.

Next, I would like to find the expected value of $p_k$ by integrating out the possible values of $m$ as follows
\begin{equation}
E[p_k]=\int_{(0,1)^N}\prod_{i\neq k}\Phi\left(\frac{f(m_k)-f(m_i)}{\sqrt{\sigma_i+\sigma_k}}\right) d\mathbf m
\end{equation}

Is it possible to use the properties of the uniform and standard normal distributions to get a more compact solution for $E[p_k]?$

Comment: A couple of things need attention: 
1) $P(X>Y,X>Z)\neq P(X>Y)P(X>Z)$ because the events are dependent, even if all the RVs are independent. 2) The RV you need is $u_i-u_k$ but it has the same dist. as $u_i+u_k$. 3) The deviation of this difference is $\sqrt{\sigma_i^2+\sigma_k^2}$, not $\sigma_i+\sigma_k$ 4) couldn't match the title with $E[p_k]$

Comment: The quantity$$p_k=\mathbb P(f(m_k)+u_k>f(m_i)+u_i, \forall  i\neq k)$$ is not a random variable, it is only the conditional probability$$p_k=\mathbb P(f(m_k)+u_k>f(m_i)+u_i, \forall  i\neq k|\mathbf m)$$that remains random because of the conditioning

Comment: Thank you! I worked on correcting your comments. I'm not sure whether I could correct for gunes' first comment, how should I do it?